# ipad mini bought London UK may 2013

Tags: ipad

I have a house in france, and just charged the ipad mini with a french plug. It blew a fuse. Can I get extra french plugs from Apple for the charger cable???
I bought this french plug from amazon. Not good!

Comment: blew the fuse ?? what did die in process ?

Answer (score 1):

Apple sells the "World Travel Adapter Kit" that includes plugs that will cover the spectrum of countries in the world.

Look here: http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB974ZM/B/apple-world-travel-adapter-kit